# 3-columns layout won't float left because of height differences

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with some columns I've created and I just can't wrap my head around whats causing it. Here's how it looks now: [image]

My code (simplified version):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-4 tall">1</div>
    <div class="col-4 very-tall">2</div>
    <div class="col-4 medium">3</div>
    <div class="col-4 tall">Why can't I be under nr 1?</div>
    <div class="col-4 tall">5</div>
    <div class="col-4 small">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-4 {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1.31578947%;
    margin-right: 1.31578947%;
    width: 30.7017544%;
}
```

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6xb35fh7/1/)** of my code.

So, **my problem**: I want the box with 'Despicable Me' to align all the way to the left, under 'How To Train Your Dragon 2'. If the top three columns have a fixed height, then it works fine, but I don't want that, i want the height of the columns to expand depending on the content.

Comment: Use `inlinne-block` or `flexbox`

Comment: If you want something like google+, you'll have to use JS

Comment: inline-block does nothing to my setup

Comment: If you know the exact height of each elment you can do it with css, otherwise look into masonry

Comment: If you want block #4 to be right under #1 without gap, you'll need JS. Something like gridify or masonry…

Comment: @BenM I m pretty sure the design doesn't have them all on an even row under the first one

Comment: @BenM right under != right, take a chill pill

Comment: @BenM, I've read. Did you? Also I've read that simple `inline-block` didn't help, so it's not about just to line blocks into rows.

Comment: I doubt he wants them in set rows. Putting them in rows will mean each column in the row will take up the same amount of height as the tallest one in the row. As he already states `If the top three columns have a fixed height, then it works fine, but I don't want that`. He wants variable heights for items, but still for them to flow around each other in the manner he stated.

Comment: OK, my bad. Looks like he does want Masonry. Sorry!

Comment: There's an obvious language barrier here, @BenM alex didn't say align to the right....

Comment: Something more like this: http://splashnology.com/

Comment: You might want to consider using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for that. For floats to work as intended all items must have the same height.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you see is expected. I think you need a three column layout and not a single div with float left on all the children, if you want to part from expected behavior.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-1"> . . . </div> 
    <div class="col-2"> . . . </div>
    <div class="col-3"> . . . </div>
</div>
```

You can also use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) as mentioned above in the comments.

Comment: I see your point.. Too bad it isn't fixable with css, it just seems like such a small problem..